# How to connect with local database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I downloaded SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). I can connect with local database using Windows Authentication, but I would like to connect with my C# app using connection string.

I check SQL Server Authentication mode here:

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbPwM.png)

I went to `Users` tab of my new created database. But I can't add new user. It says that I don't have permission.

I also went to `sys` user properties, but I can't change password anywhere:

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3hmD.png)

So what should I do? I want to connect with database on VPS with my c# app.s

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the current user that is logged in (Windows Authentication) then you setup the connection string as follows:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

If you mean that you want to use a SQL Authenticated account, you need to add the SQL login and user, map it to the database you want, and then you can use the following syntax:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

You can search for more documentation on setting up your App.Config file to have connection strings, and any tweaks to the connection string itself can be found at:

https://connectionstrings.com/sql-server/